# ORDER BY and CASE

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, case

I have the following script in SQL:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[getRequests]
@SortBy             VARCHAR(50) = 'Date'
AS
SELECT  [ReqDate], [RequestorOrg], [RequestCategory],
        [ReqDescription], [OrgCountVote]
ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (oldest first)'   THEN [ReqDate]          END ASC, [OrgCountVote] DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (newest first)'   THEN [ReqDate]          END DESC, [OrgCountVote] ,
        CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Number of Votes'       THEN [OrgCountVote]     END DESC, reqdate,
        CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Organisation'          THEN [RequestorOrg]     END,
        CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Category'              THEN [RequestCategory]  END;
```

The first two cases in `ORDER BY` have more than one column to sort on.

When I attempt to save the script, it gives me the following message:

> Msg 169, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getRequests, Line 8
>   A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.

How can I ensure that the *columns are unique*?

Comment: You have to rewrite the whole SQL statement with IF clauses for the sorting to work as you want.

Comment: You need one  "case" only and you need an "end".

Comment: Tim, it gives me the same error message.

Comment: sorry didn't see you other case order by .

Comment: Solved it! The problem was that the combination of the columns in the first two cases was the same. I removed the second column in the second case, and viola! it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use this type of stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[getRequests]
@SortBy             VARCHAR(50) = 'Date'
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) 

SET @sql = 'SELECT  [ReqDate], [RequestorOrg], [RequestCategory], [ReqDescription], [OrgCountVote] ' +
           'ORDER BY ' +
                CASE @SortBy
                    WHEN 'Date (oldest first)' THEN '[ReqDate] ASC, [OrgCountVote] DESC'
                    WHEN 'Date (newest first)' THEN '[ReqDate] DESC, [OrgCountVote] '
                    WHEN 'Number of Votes'     THEN '[OrgCountVote] DESC, reqdate'
                    WHEN 'Organisation'        THEN '[RequestorOrg]'
                    WHEN 'Category'            THEN '[RequestCategory]'
                END
EXEC(@sql)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `OrgCountVote` field. The fields enclosed within the `CASE` statement are fine... at least, it worked fine on my test system (Sql Server 2008 R2). Even so, I'd recommend adding a default `ELSE` clause to each of those case conditions, and you should also know that this can result in some really awful query plans (bad performance). For this kind of thing, you'll get *much* better performance doing your ordering in the client code.

That said, you can accomplish what you need like this:

```
ORDER BY
  --first level
    CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (oldest first)' THEN [ReqDate]
         WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (newest first)' THEN CAST(CAST([ReqDate]-'1970-01-01' AS decimal(38,10))*-24*60*60*1000+0.5 as bigint)
         WHEN @SortBy = 'Number of Votes'     THEN [OrgCountVote] * -1 
         WHEN @SortBy = 'Organisation'        THEN [RequestorOrg]
         WHEN @SortBy = 'Category'            THEN [RequestCategory]  END, 
  --second level
    CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (oldest first)' THEN [OrgCountVote] * -1
         WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (newest first)' THEN [OrgCountVote]
         WHEN @SortBy = 'Number of Votes'     THEN reqdate
         ELSE NULL END
```

I need to explain the `Date (newest first)` entry for a moment. If you just do a simple datediff, you end up overflowing the integer type. All the rest of that long expression is just to turn the date field into a number that you can multiply by -1, and thus invert the sort order. Credit to this link for how to do it:

> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/51cfea50-f915-4bac-bf7d-d053329086cd/difference-of-dates-in-millisecond?forum=transactsql

If you don't need millisecond granularity (ie: you're only storing date values, with all zeroes in the time component) or if you don't care it's not perfect here and there (records at nearly the same time might be out of order, perhaps if this were be an extremely rare occurrence for your data), then you could greatly simplify that expression and just take, say, the number of seconds since the unix epoch or the number of minutes or days since the Sql Server epoch.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the logic from using the complicated `ORDER BY` list of columns to using `IF` clauses and specifying multiple select statements and `ORDER BY`s.

Like:

```
If @SortBy = 'Date....' then
Begin
    -- SQL with the single order by group...
End
Else if @SortBy =... Then...
Begin

End
```

Comment: The reason for doing it like this is to reduce the chances of mistakenly omitting a change from the bigger SQL statement (I reduced the code to a manageable chunk to illustrate my problem. The actual SP is 149 lines long, with 4 IF statements already). The CASE works perfectly if I don't have the second _Date_-case.

Answer (score 0):

This may give you similar results if you have to use case:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[getRequests]
@SortBy             VARCHAR(50) = 'Date'
AS
SELECT  [ReqDate], [RequestorOrg], [RequestCategory],
    [ReqDescription], [OrgCountVote]
FROM requests
ORDER BY 
CASE 
WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (oldest first)' THEN Datediff(day, '2010-1-1', [ReqDate]) 
WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (newest first)'   THEN [ReqDate]          
WHEN @SortBy = 'Number of Votes'       THEN [RequestorOrg]     
WHEN @SortBy = 'Category'              THEN [RequestCategory]  
END DESC, 
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (newest first)'    THEN OrgCountVote
WHEN @SortBy = 'Number of Votes'       THEN [OrgCountVote] 
ELSE '' END
```

Again, you may NOT want to do it. And the performance may be effected.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out quite a dynamic way to do the ORDER BY. In my example below, I can add as many WHEN's as I wish, it will just step through them and pick up the relevant statements.

```
ORDER BY   
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (oldest first)'   THEN [ReqDateTime]      END ASC,  
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (oldest first)'   THEN [OrgCountVote]     END DESC,  
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (newest first)'   THEN [ReqDateTime]      END DESC,  
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Date (newest first)'   THEN [OrgCountVote]     END DESC,  
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Number of Votes'       THEN [OrgCountVote]     END DESC,   
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Number of Votes'       THEN [ReqDateTime]      END DESC,  
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Organisation'          THEN [RequestorOrg]     END,  
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Status'                THEN ReqStatus          END,  
CASE WHEN @SortBy = 'Category'              THEN [RequestCategory]  END;
```

I didn't have to worry about the ELSE, as the parameter has a default value assigned to it, and therefore will always have one of these statements:

```
@SortBy             VARCHAR(50) = 'Status'
```